# Inductance in Superconductors

Tags: electric-circuits, superconductivity, inductance

[image]

This is a picture I got from a question in this website, it seems totally fine, but if you try looking it gain, is the heater placed in the wrong position? Because as I know current takes the path of least resistance (which in this case is path on the right side), thus we could conclude that there's no potential difference since the total resistance of the circuit is zero? Therefore current is not induced or 'excited'. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

> is the heater placed in the wrong position? Because as I know current takes the path of least resistance (which in this case is path on the right side)

Best that you forget you ever heard that “current takes the path of least resistance heuristic”. Circuit theory is based on Kirchoff’s voltage and current laws and the current/voltage characteristics of circuit elements. Here, the inductor has no resistance, but the voltage is proportional to the change in the current.

In this case, solving KVL with the current source in parallel with the resistor and inductor give a standard RL circuit with a time constant. The current through the inductor exponentially approaches an asymptote if the current source remains constant.

Comment: Can you explain it in an easier way? I have no idea of asymptote and RL.

Comment: Do you know KVL and KCL? Do you know Ohm’s law and $v=L di/dt$ ? Are you familiar with node voltage analysis or mesh current analysis?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Then I think you need to start with a textbook on circuit theory. That is far too much material to cover on an online forum. That should be thoroughly understood before attempting to learn about superconductivity.